# Can you define a UTF-16 string in GNU "as" assembler?

Tags: windows, unicode, x86, mingw, gnu-assembler

I am trying to make a proof of concept program to see if GNU `as` has a way to define UTF-16 strings similarly to .asciz without resorting to having to define the UTF-16 string using external C.

Does GNU assembler have a UTF-16 version of .asciz to make the following code cleaner? (compiled with `gcc test.S -o test`)

```
    .global _WinMain@16

    .section .text

// windows application entry takes 16 bytes on stack
// that it is responsible of getting rid of 
// along with return address, before returning.
_WinMain@16:

    // ascii version
    push $_ascii_msg
    call _puts
    add $4, %esp        

    // brute force unicode version
    push $_brute_unicode_msg
    call __putws
    add $4, %esp            

    mov $0, %eax
    ret $16

_ascii_msg:    
    .asciz "Hello, World!"

// ascii conveniently occupies first 256 bytes of the unicode table.        
_brute_unicode_msg:
    .word 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', 0
```

Comment: I don't believe that GNU Assembler has any support for unicode. If you used an assembler like _NASM_ there is some support for this.

Comment: yeah but unfortunately nasm doesn't come with a standard windows linker. that seems unfortunate.

Comment: NASM isn't a linker. It is just an assembler. You can output win32 and win64 compatible objects that can be linked with any linker that supports those objects.

Comment: yeah, that's the odd thing about nasm. it does its' job amazingly well but it takes a very sophisticated developer to have the will to look for a linker that isn't already there, and be willing to understand how cross linking nasm objects and non nasm objects works. I mean i've been programming for over 10 years and I'd need to do a bit of reading to understand how to reason about it.

Comment: MinGW `ld` linker will use NASM objects. _LD_ is part of the standard binutils package. Is also the linker that GCC uses on the backend

Comment: is it really as simple as rewriting the code above as 32 bit nasm and use ld? I mean it's using windows api's __putws and msvcrt's _puts. i'm not sure how to translate .global neither which is another issue. Ok as expected I got `"_puts" undefined`, followed by `test.asm:6: error: binary output format does not support external references`

Comment: ooh you're right i just had to `nasm -f elf32 test.asm && gcc test.o -o test`. how exciting, thanks for getting me to try it! It seems like it doesn't become a PE before linkage.

Comment: FWIW, for my Win32 code, I prefer golink. Works well, is easy to use and set up.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Given that he is already using MinGW GCC (_LD_ will alo be available as part of MinGW's binutils) why bother with a separate linker?

Comment: I heard about golink. anyways I&amp;#39;m sidetracing, the question was about whether gnu as definitely supports or doesn&amp;#39;t this feature. If it doesn&amp;#39;t it&amp;#39;s odd because its equivalent to making external c and linking to it; or making a c preprocessor to implement this feature and expand it to Unicode numbers and running it on the .S file before assembling.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: You're right. I don't use MingW, so I tried to find something independent.

Comment: If you can use NASM the documentation has some examples using Unicode. http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html in section _3.4.5 Unicode Strings_

Comment: say in *masm* can define macro `WSTRING macro text
 ALIGN 2
 FORC arg, <text>
 DW '&arg'
 ENDM
 DW 0
endm` and use it as `unicode_msg: WSTRING <Hello, World>`